# Правильная реализация напоминаний(заданий по расписанию) на уровне БД

Tags: postgresql, база-данных

Добрый вечер! Ребят, кто делал напоминания(задания по расписанию) в своих проектах!? поделитесь опытом, как лучше все организовать.

Вот к примеру есть таблица **TASK** с полями **id** и **name**, и нужно чтобы он выполнялся по определенному расписанию. Соответственно нужна например выборка тасков которые будут выполнятся за **сегодня** или например за **неделю** в общем в зависимости от того как указал юзер.

Варианты которые с ходу пришли на ум:

1. Добавляем поле-строку в формате cron к примеру "`0 0 * * *`" - (каждый день в полночь)

   Очень удобно, но как потом делать выборку, нужно средствами бд парсить вначале эту строку потом по результату составлять запрос, но самое главное когда таблица разрастется парсин плохо скажется на скорости выборки.
2. Тоже самое, но только каждый параметр выносим в отдельное поле и я так понимаю, если нужно указывать несколько месяцев или несколько дней, то храним их как битовую маску.
   Плюс в том что избавляемся от парсинга, но получаем новую проблему выборка по маске, на сколько она быстро и удобно будет работать?
3. Делаем полноценную структуру таблиц, под месяцы, дни, часы свою таблицу со связями.
4. Отдаем все серверу приложения, держим отдельный кэш для этих целей и синхронизируем его с бд в принципе можно использовать формат cron как в первом варианте

Ни один способ мне интуитивно не нравится. Посоветуйте, как лучше сделать те кто уже сталкивался с подобными задачами. Может есть более красивый и правильный способ.

База у меня postgresql.

Comment: 1. Прям вот чувствую тут деление по модулю. Берём Unixtime и делим на секунды нужные.
2. Вариант 2 - это писать время следующего выполнения, а по выполнению смещать его.

Comment: Возможно я не совсем точно обозначил вопрос, но в данном случае интересует именно организация хранения данных, для того чтобы в последствии была возможность быстрой и удобной выборки из бд.

А сама реализация выполнения этих заданий это уже другой вопрос:)

Comment: Может есть еще у кого-нибудь мысли по этому поводу? Или не совсем понятен вопрос?